# How can I automatically turn off civirules after a given period?

Tags: civirules

I have a rules that should perform action only until a certain date. What would be the best way to handle this situation so that after a given date the specific rule would be turned off automatically? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your Trigger in the rule, I would suggest just adding a time-based condition.

If contribution, add criteria «Field Value Comparison» for «Date Received» and set the operator to less than the desired date.

If activity, use activity date. If new membership, use membership start date, and so on...

Comment: It wouldn’t disable the rule, but it would prohibit the rule from performing any action. And then you can have a general review of you rules at certain intervals...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks

Comment: The date received condition when a contribution is added does not seem to trigger. Not sure if it’s a bug of civil rules!!

Comment: @Tapash I would assume you have to set the date by the exact same format as the raw date values in your database...?

Comment: Thanks. What is the best way to find the raw date format?

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL-tables? Try looking it up there?

Comment: yes I do. Many thanks for your tips.